# Determine if objects stored in an std::vector are trivially copyable

Tags: c++, static-assert

This code doesn't compile, since the static assert fails.

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

class A {
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> v;
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<decltype(v[0])>::value);
    return 0;
}
```

If, on the other hand, I replace the `decltype(v[0])` with `A`, then it compiles. The problem is that `v[0]` is of type reference to `A` rather than `A`. How can I make it work using `v` in some way?

Comment: [`std::remove_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector` has a `value_type` member that is the type given in the parameter list of the vector for the element type.  Using that gives you

```
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<decltype(v)::value_type>::value);
```

Alternatively you can remove the reference qualification from `v[0]` like

```
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<std::remove_reference<decltype(v[0])>::type>::value);
// or if you want to remove all cv and ref qualifications
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<std::remove_cvref<decltype(v[0])>::type>::value);
// or if you want to remove all cv, ref, and array qualifications
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<std::decay<decltype(v[0])>::type>::value);
```

---

Do note that if you are using a newer version of C++ like C++17 or C++20 then you can use the `_t` and `_v` versions of the type traits to simplify the code to

```
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<decltype(v)::value_type>);

static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(v[0])>>);

static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(v[0])>>);

static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<std::decay_t<decltype(v[0])>>);
```

Comment: @NathanOliver wouldn't [`std::remove_cvref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cvref) would be more appropriate than [`std::decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay)?

Comment: @user3749105 why would you not want to use the cleaner `decltype(v)::value_type` instead of the uglier `std::remove_reference<decltype(v[0])>::type`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are right --- one should go with the first option. My comment is misleading, since in my "real world situation", `v` is a const reference to `std::vector<A>`, which is why the first option doesn't compile. I deleted the comment.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I keep forgetting they added that into C++20.  Added in.

Comment: @NathanOliver oh, I didn't even notice the version on it. Good catch